# Djoser user_list setting AllowAny not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have created login Api using Djoser for authentication.
I want to get the list of users using a GET api call (/api/auth/users/ endpoint) but I get an error saying

```
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

I have added djoser settings in setting.py file like this

```
DJOSER={
    'user': ['djoser.permissions.AllowAny'],
    'user_list': ['djoser.permissions.AllowAny'],
    'SERIALIZERS':{
        'user_create':'restapi_subserv.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user':'restapi_subserv.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',

    }
}
```

But Still, I get the error.
Am I missing something?

Please let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 2):

set hide_users to false

```
DJOSER = {
    'HIDE_USERS': False,
    'PERMISSIONS': {

    'user': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'],
    'user_list': ['rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'],

    },

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify that you're trying to override the default permissions just like you did with the serializers:

```
DJOSER = {
    'PERMISSIONS': {
        'user': ['djoser.permissions.AllowAny'],
        'user_list': ['djoser.permissions.AllowAny'],
    },
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'restapi_subserv.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'restapi_subserv.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',

    }
}
```

The documentation doesn't do a very good job at specifying this.